# How do I split constructed jstree into 2 parts

Tags: jstree

I am using jstree and jstree grid for contructing my tree structure. Can I split the constructed jstree into 2 parts?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you build a second tree?

Comment: No , I already constructed a jstree. Now I need to split that tree in two .

Comment: I mean why can't you split your data into two parts and build two trees?

Comment: No, Its like one person constructed a tree and another person will split that tree into many parts

Comment: Did you solve your question?

Comment: No, i can't split that tree. So I used checkbox plugin for selecting particular node. By using it, I selected the nodes i want and stored it in DB. The codes I used for selecting checked nodes are                                  var checked =  $("#temporary1").jstree(true).get_selected(true);           var selected_node= JSON.stringify(checked);

Answer (score 0):

You can split it with code as below.
Check demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/aa67p77a/)

```
$("#tree1")
    .on("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {

        // destroy second tree and remove DOM elements
        if ($("#tree2").find('ul').length > 0) {
            $("#tree2").jstree('destroy').empty();
        }

        // get json format for branch to move selected node/branch from first tree
        var json = data.instance.get_json(data.node);

        // init second tree with new data
        $("#tree2").jstree({
            "core": {
                "data": json
            }
        });

        // remove selected node/branch from the first tree
        $("#tree1").jstree('delete_node', [data.node.id]);
        $("#" + data.node.id).remove();

    })
    .jstree({
        "core": {
            "data": data1
        }
    })
```