# Get checked and undetermined nodes

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have been selected a node in jstree. I can get a json value of the selected nodes. But the problem is, I want the parent nodes of the child node , upto root

Comment: what you tried so far..??

Comment: For selecting checked nodes, i used this code                                             var checked =  $("#temporary1").jstree(true).get_selected(true);

Comment: But i cant get the parent node values. so i used below code. But it showing undefined                                                  $("#temporary1").find(".jstree-undetermined").each(function (i) {
checked.push($(this).parent().parent().attr("id"));
});

Comment: You could encourage more people answer you new questions if you provide some feedback on your previous - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940429/how-do-i-split-constructed-jstree-into-2-parts

Comment: Yeah, I gave feedback. Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the code as below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/tce9uuo2/).

```
   function getParentNode(node) {
       return $('#tree').jstree().get_parent(node);
   }

   var nodes = $('#tree').jstree().get_selected('full'), parentNodes = [], parentTexts = [];

   nodes.forEach( function(node) {
      var parentNode = getParentNode(node);
      while (parentNode && parentNode !=='#') {
            if (parentNodes.indexOf(parentNode) === -1 ) { 
              parentNodes.push( parentNode );
              parentTexts.push( $('#tree').jstree().get_node(parentNode).text );
          }
          parentNode = getParentNode(parentNode);
      }
 })
```

**UPDATE**

The code you use could look like:

```
var checked_ids = [], checked_ids1 = [];
$("#temporary1").find(".jstree-undetermined").each(
    function(i, element) {
        var nodeId = $(element).closest('.jstree-node').attr("id");
        // alert( nodeId );
        checked_ids.push( nodeId );
        checked_ids1.push( $('#temporary1').jstree().get_node( nodeId ).text );
    }
);
```

Comment: Yeah, Its fine to work. Can you please tell me, How to get the text values instead of Id

Comment: For getting the values of indetermined state, I used these codes                                             $("#temporary1").find(".jstree-undetermined").each(function (i, element) {
            alert($(element).closest('.jstree-node').attr("text"));
            checked_ids.push($(element).attr("text"));
        });          But I am getting the values as undefined. How can i get?

Comment: Generally you can get the text as `$('#tree').jstree().get_node(nodeId).text );` I updated answer and fiddle. There is always a `root` element for is not visible and has an `undefined` text.

Comment: var checked_ids = [];
        $("#temporary1").find(".jstree-undetermined").each(function (i, element) {
            alert($(element).closest('.jstree-node').attr("id"));
            checked_ids.push($(element).attr("id"));
        }); 
  
  alert(checked_ids);
  var checked_ids1 = [];
  checked_ids1.push($('#temporary1').jstree().get_node(checked_ids).text );  I used like this. Eventhough i am getting undefined as a value

Comment: I updated code to avoid `undefined` text for root node. Or what was the question?

Comment: If ,My parent node is not a root node. At that time, how can i get the text value of parent node

Comment: Yeah i used the code. But its not working. It returns an empty value.

Comment: element.id doesn't return any value

Comment: Do you get an alert with the id - `alert( $(element).closest('.jstree-node').attr("id") );` ?

Comment: Yeah , I got that alert which shows id. But i cant get the text value.. Not yet solved the problem

Comment: That's because you are trying to get text of an icon - you iterate icons with `jstree-undetermined` class. I updated answer and fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/tce9uuo2/ so it would search for text of the node.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jstree's get_path. The way I have it below will return to the console an array of the parents of the selected node.

> ```
>    * get the path to a node, either consisting of node texts, or of node IDs, optionally glued together (otherwise an array)
> ```

```
        $('#jstree').jstree().on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
            console.log(data.instance.get_path(data.node, undefined, true));
        });
```